# Datatable to Gridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am working on a project where i have to populate  the grid view using data table 
so far i have  fill the data table from the query and i have displayed the result on data grid view using `datagridview.datasource = dt`

but now i want to to show the specific columns and its data to grid view   here is my sample form[image]
in this form i have  fill the grid view  with the data source of data table  but  now i want to display the result in the other grid with specific column  like  if im_qty > 0 then it show as purchase Qty  other wise sale qty, also im rate to the rate column  how do i achieve that  please guide me ..

Comment: You have to set `dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false` and add your own columns with `dataGridView.Columns.Add(DataGridViewColumn)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use linq operations to filter your datatable as you wish, rather than filter from your table. pleas refer these links.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1